# Generate ID fast and with high probability of uniqueness

Tags: java, random, uuid

I want to generate ID to event that occur in my application.

The event frequency is up to the user load, so it might occur hundreds-thousand of time per second.

I can't afford using `UUID.randomUUID()` because it might be problematic in performance matters - Take a look at [this](http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100317-why-java-s-random-number-generation-might-block-my-application-under-linux.html).

I thought of generating ID as follows:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() + ";" + Long.toString(_random.nextLong())
```

When `_random` is a static `java.util.Random` my class is holding.

My questions are:

1. Do you think the distribution of this combination will be good enough to my needs?
2. Does Java's Random implementation related to the current time and therefore the fact I'm combining the two is dangerous?

Comment: *"every couple of seconds .. might be problematic in performance"*  That is hardly 'CPU busting' performance.  A couple of thousand times a second might count.

Comment: `...will be good enough to my needs` what's your exact needs? how many users you expect? what is your server specifications?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, your are right, I updated my question.

Comment: A change from "every couple of seconds" to "hundreds-thousand of time per second" is very big. Do you have any evidence that says how often the id will be required, or are you just guessing/thinking of worst case scenarios?

Comment: Hi @Disco3, trust me, I'm not making this up. My application runs as java-agent on users application, then, the frequency is up to the number of users that use the user application.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the following.

```
final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);
```

and

```
long l = counter.getAndIncrement(); // takes less than 10 nano-seconds most of the time.
```

This will be unique within your system and across restarts provided you average less than one million per second.

Even at this rate, the number will not overflow for some time.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new java.util.Date(Long.MAX_VALUE/1000));
    }
}
```

prints

```
Sun Jan 10 04:00:54 GMT 294247
```

EDIT: In the last 8 years I have switched to using nanosecond wall clock and memory-mapped files to ensure uniqueness across processes on the same machine. The code is available here. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/blob/ea/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/MappedUniqueTimeProvider.java

Comment: I think "average" is not as relevant as what he is bounded at.

Comment: @frankc Which bound were you thinking of?

Comment: I mean that if he averages only 100,000 per second but his distrubution of arrivals is skewed such that he has several million plus spikes, it could be problematic.

Comment: He could have very high spikes, but as long as the average for the period the application stayed up was below one million/second, it doesn't matter. e.g. say it is one billion spike and then nothing to 1000 seconds, he is still ok.  If this is a real worry, he could multiple by 10,000 and the id will clock over in the year 31,197 instead.

Comment: This one doesn't guarantee uniqueness in distributed environments.

Comment: @KetanDhamasana It doesn't guarantee uniqueness across processes in the same machine.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent possible collisions I would suggest you to somehow integrate users' unique ids into the generated id. You can do this either adding user id to directly to  the generated id

```
System.currentTimeMillis() + ";" + Long.toString(_random.nextLong()) + userId
```

or you can use separate `_random` for each user that uses the user's id as its [seed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29).

Answer (score 2):

`UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();` is less than 8 times slower, after warming up, 0.015 ms versus 0.0021 ms on my PC. That would be a positive argument for UUID - for me.

1. One could shift the random long a bit to the right, so time is more normative, sequencing.
2. No, there is a pseudo random distribution involved.

Comment: UUID use SecureRandom, which might be evil... http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100317-why-java-s-random-number-generation-might-block-my-application-under-linux.html

Comment: The first sentence doesn't really make sense to me. Why is "8 times slower" a "positive argument for UUID"?

Comment: Because 15 µs is [tiny](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/every-programmer-should-know). Arguable.

Comment: @JoopEggen: How about: "On my PC, `randomUUID()` needs 0.015 ms. This is still 8 times slower than your code (0.0021 ms after warmup) but is fast enough to generate 66'000 keys/s."?

Comment: Right, UUID is too slow for that throughput. @PeterLawrey's answer seems more appropiate.

Comment: @AaronDigulla still thanks; missed reading your comment; no need to change the answer text _now_.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't afford using UUID.randomUUID() because it might be problematic

And it might not. Currently, you're solving a problem that might not exist. I suggest to use an interface so you can easily swap out the generated ID but stick to this generator on which many smart people have spent a lot of time to make it right.

Your own solution might work in many cases but the corner cases are important and you will only see those after a few years of experience.

That said, combining the current time + `Random` should give pretty unique IDs. But they are easy to guess and insecure.

Comment: UUID use SecureRandom, which might be evil... http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100317-why-java-s-random-number-generation-might-block-my-application-under-linux.html

Comment: I know that but that still doesn't mean it will affect you. Linux has become better at generating random numbers in huge amounts. And you can configure Java to use `/dev/urandom` for less secure but non-blocking randomness.

Comment: I work for a Messaging System which handles lots of lots of concurrency and I found a performance issue in a place where UUID.randomUUID() is being called, it seems that it doesn't work well in applications where super performance is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library to avoid reinventing the wheel.

For example, JUG (https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator) can generate 5 millions time-based UUIDs per second (https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator/blob/master/release-notes/FAQ) :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

UUID uuid = Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate();
```